# How can I match the whole regex not the subexpression

Tags: python, regex

Say, I have the following `regex` to search a series of room number:

```
import re
re.findall(r'\b(\d)\d\1\b','101 102 103 201 202 203')
```

I want to search for the room number whose first and last digit are the same (101 and 202). The above code gives

```
['1','2']
```

which corresponding to the subexpression `(\d)`. But how can it return the whole room number like 101 and 202?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
print [i for i,j in re.findall(r'\b((\d)\d\2)\b','101 102 103 201 202 203')]
```

or

```
print [i[0] for i in re.findall(r'\b((\d)\d\2)\b','101 102 103 201 202 203')]
```

You can use `list comprehension` here.You need only room numbers so include only `i`.basically `re.findall` return all groups in a regex.So you need `2` groups.The first is will have room numbers and second will be used for matching.So we can extract just the first out of the tuple of `2`.

Comment: Or `print [i.group(0) for i in re.finditer(r'\b((\d)\d\2)\b','101 102 103 201 202 203')]` :)

Comment: @stribizhev yeah another good approach......... are you learning all languages :P

Comment: I have been doing that for half a year. A thrilling adventure. Can't help it :)

Comment: @stribizhev :O.... cool!!!!!!! so jack of all trades master of none or master of all :P